# Standard library algorithm to average the difference between adjacent elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, c++-chrono

I have a `std::vector<std:::chrono::system_clock::time_point>` values.

I want to average the time difference in milliseconds between adjacent elements.  The container requires at least 2 elements and I am having trouble with the averaging function.  I was using std::accumulate but I don;t think I can quite get that to work as I get a ton of compiler errors.  The lambda below which I am using as a reduce function with the accumulate algorithm

```
    auto gLambda = [&](
        system_clock::time_point t1, system_clock::time_point t2) {
            return duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    };
```

works fine though

The [live coliru demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a0b237e05d3dd3f)

```
int main()
{
    // lambda called with adjacent samples from the deque
    auto gLambda = [&](
        system_clock::time_point t1, system_clock::time_point t2) {
            return duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    };
    
    // this line compiles and the lambda seems to do the right thing
    const auto t1 = system_clock::now();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(55ms);
    const auto t2 = system_clock::now();
    // result is 55 as expected
    auto result = gLambda(t1, t2);    
    std::cout << result << std::endl;    
    // create a vector of 10 timestamps
    std::vector<system_clock::time_point> timeStamps;    
    for (auto i=0; i<10; i++) {
        timeStamps.emplace_back(system_clock::now());
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(15ms);
    }
    // THIS LINE CAUSES THE COMPILATION ERROR
    auto result1 = std::accumulate(timeStamps.cbegin(), timeStamps.cend(), 0.0, gLambda);
    std::cout << result1 << std::endl;
}
```

results in the following compilation errors that I do not understand.

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/numeric:62,
                 from main.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_numeric.h: In instantiation of '_Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >*, std::vector<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > > > >; _Tp = double; _BinaryOperation = main()::<lambda(std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point, std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point)>]':
main.cpp:30:88:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_numeric.h:169:22: error: no match for call to '(main()::<lambda(std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point, std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point)>) (double&, const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >&)'
  169 |  __init = __binary_op(_GLIBCXX_MOVE_IF_20(__init), *__first);
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:12:20: note: candidate: 'main()::<lambda(std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point, std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point)>'
   12 |     auto gLambda = [&](
      |                    ^
main.cpp:12:20: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'double' to 'std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point' {aka 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >'}
```

Comment: Won't this just equal `(last - first) / length`?  Everything else cancels, it's a telescoping sum.

Comment: The third argument (initial value) to `accumulate` is `0.0`, which is a `double`.  Is this convertible to a `time_point`?  That's what the first argument of the lambda will turn out to be.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am not sure how to convert a double to a timepoint, perhaps I tried setting the initial value explicitly set to the timepoint now() instead of 0.0 and that generated just as many errors along the lines of 'no known conversion for argument 1 from 'long int' to 'const std::chrono::time_point'

Comment: @johnco3 Probably -- I have to play around with your example a little bit more.  But definitely the error is a classic `std::accumulate` one, where the initial value argument doesn't match (or is not convertible to) the first argument in the functor / lambda / etc.  The last line in the error listing basically states this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks I think the same - I would appreciate it if you could help me with the example.  I wasted about an hour experimenting to no avail.

Comment: I don't think accumulate is the right tool for the job, it'll sum every element not adjacent pairs, a manual for loop is likely to be the best solution

Comment: @johnco3 I think a regular loop would also be a little easier.  Anyway, I am no expert in manipulating the various time types off the top of my head (ashamed) in C++, but [this compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d704ec0e0d9e635e).  Whether it does the job is a different story.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - funny you should do that, I tried something similar myself https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb9c1f10c8e5fd62 :) looks like we had the same idea.  I think I need to choose a slightly different algorithm as Alan Birtles points out.  I've used adjacent_find before - perhaps that will yield the right result if I accumulate the differences between adjacent elements and then finally divide by size-1 of the vector

Comment: Yeah, `adjacent_find` that returns a `false` in the lambda will work.  I've been scolded that using `adjacent_find` to do "pair work" like this is an abuse of the function, but if it works...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie user sehe warns about abusing adjacent_find and prefers std::transform with binary predicates... hmmm need to see what all that's about - thanks for your help.  I appreciate it

Comment: Take a look at `std::inner_product` as well, it might be applicable for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [cigien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8372853/cigien) suggested in the comments, here's how to do it with `inner_product`:

```
auto result = inner_product(
                  timeStamps.begin() + 1, timeStamps.end(),
                  timeStamps.begin(), 0ms,
                  [](auto x, auto y) {return x + y;},
                  [](auto x, auto y) {return round<milliseconds>(x - y);})
              / (timeStamps.size() - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the implementation, what a really elegant abuse of the `std::inner_product` - kudos to @cigien.  Way more intuitive than abusing `std::adjacent_find` or `std::transform_reduce` which was what I was thinking about using.

Comment: One of the unintuitive things you coded (which I think should be mentioned) was the use of the 0ms - initializer.  I struggled with this as I needed to have an initial value that was convertible to a time point (an initial value for the accumulator).  Initially I used double of 0.0 which resulted in about 20 pages of errors with the actual error buried somewhere in the middle :).    Nice one and great answer - which works!!

Comment: now that I am abusing inner_product I was wondering if you could spot where this is going wrong, I am trying to calculate the standard deviation (of packet jitter) using timestamps and the partial results (the sum of the squares of the individual packet times - the average packet time) look way off, I was expecting a standard deviation near 0 in my live coliru demo https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4823684c18c05680

Comment: It looks like for your first operation you are `(t[i]-t[i] - mean)^2`, when you want `(t[i]-t[i-1] - mean)^2`.  I believe the first range needs to start with `timeStamps.begin()+1`.  And you are missing dividing by N (i.e. `(timeStamps.size() - 1)`.